# ¿Cómo hacer un script que active un entorno virtual?

Tags: python, ubuntu, bash

Quiero un script en el Bash de Ubuntu para activar un entorno virtual de Python.

No sé como hacerlo, sé como activar el entorno virtual manualmente pero quiero crear uno donde yo indique el nombre del entorno virtual y posteriormente se active.

Para ser más explícito, ya pude hacerlo en Windows y aquí está el ejemplo:

```
@echo off
echo Bienvenido %USERNAME%.
set /p environment="Introduce el nombre de tu entorno virtual: "
echo Ahora el entorno %environment%, esta activado, escribe "deactivate" para desactivarlo.
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Envs\%environment%_env\Scripts\activate
```

Ese es un archivo .bat en Windows que funciona exactamente para lo que lo necesito, incluso ya lo tengo en el PATH para poder utilizar desde cualquier parte.

Pero no sé como crear un script parecido para el Bash de Ubuntu.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

**EDIT 2:**

De acuerdo a las respuestas se generó el siguiente script para resolver el problema:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Welcome $USER.
echo Introduce el nombre del entorno virtual:
read name
~/envs/$name/bin/activate
```

Adicional a ello, se le asigno a cada script permisos para que se pudieran ejecutar (tanto al propio, como al que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta del entorno virtual [activate]):

```
chmod +x activar.sh
```

No hay errores mostrados en terminal, pero no se activa el entorno virtual, así que sigue sin resolverse el problema.

## SOLUCIÓN:

Primero se elige el directorio donde se guardaran los entorno virtuales, en este caso: ~/envs/

Se procede a crear el script (nombre_script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bienvenido, $USER!"
read -p "Introduce el nombre del entorno virtual: " ENV
source ~/envs/$ENV/bin/activate
```

**DETALLES:**

- Puedes cambiar la tercera línea de código por (esta va a imprimir un salto de línea):

  ```
  echo "Introduce el nombre del entorno virtual: "
  read ENV
  ```
- La línea del comando "source" no debe llevar comillas, de lo contrario aparecerá un error indicando que no se ha encontrado el archivo o directorio.
- Es indiferente darle permisos de ejecución al script (chmod +x script.sh), con o sin permisos va a funcionar. **Importante** aquí, este permiso solo se necesita cuando se quiere ejecutar el script de esta manera:

  ```
  ./script.sh
  ```

  - Al menos para este caso en particular no se debe hacer así, ya que si bien a la hora de ejecutar el script no marcará ningún error, este tampoco activará el entorno virtual.

**EJECUTAR EL SCRIPT:**
Se puede hacer especificando la ruta dónde este guardado el script, por ejemplo, si estuvieramos en la carpeta ~/proyecto/, y el script estuviera en la carpeta personal "~", sería de la siguiente manera:

```
. ~/script.sh
```

Para hacer que sea más cómodo usarlo podemos mover el script a la carpeta "/usr/local/bin", y ahora podemos ejecutar el script desde cualquier directorio de la siguiente manera:

```
. script.sh
```

*Solución probada en: terminal de Ubuntu Mate 17.04, y Bash de Ubuntu en Windows 10 (subsistema Ubuntu 16.04).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La diferencia sustancial es que en [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) se lee del teclado por medio de *read*.

```
echo "Welcome $USER."
echo "Introduce el nombre del entorno virtual:"
read name
source ~"/envs/$name/bin/activate"
```

**Nota:** en Linux la keyword `~/` es un shortcut hacia */home/usuario/*, por lo que la ruta del script se resolvería en: */home/usuario/envs/[nombre del env]/activate*.

El último paso es mover el script hacia */usr/local/bin* para que esté disponible globalmente, de esta manera, desde cualquier directorio puedes llamar al script solo por su nombre: *. nombrescript.sh*.

---

#### Actualización

Puedes hacerlo más dinámico y compacto usando argumentos nombrados para evitar la conversación. Para esto de puedes valer de [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "n:" option
do
  case "${option}"
  in
  n) name=${OPTARG};;
  esac
done

source ~/envs/$name/bin/activate
```

Solo debes pasarle el argumento *-n* para indicar el nombre del entorno virtual:

```
. nombrescript.sh -n prueba
. nombrescript.sh -n prueba
```

Comment: Prefiero hacerlo como lo colocaste en el primer script, pero aún así no me funcionó. El script no da a resaltar ningún error, pero no lo activa. Lo único que cambie fue la ruta, ya que los entorno virtuales generados en ubuntu suelen tener esta ruta, ej: ~/env/bin/activate

Comment: @codenoschool probé ambos scripts antes de publicar la respuesta y todo ok. Se supone cambiando la ruta no defería afecta en nada. ¿Puedes poner tu versión del script en [pastebin](https://pastebin.com)?

Comment: De acuerdo, aquí esta el enlace https://pastebin.com/jquQxRGp , algo adicional que hice fue asignarle permisos a los scripts "chmod +x activar.sh" y tambien al de "activate" dentro de la carpeta del entorno virtual, de lo contrario no me deja ejecutarlos. No aparece ningún error, solamente no se activa el entorno virtual.

Comment: @codenoschool código adaptado a tu estructura de directorios. Ejecuta los scripts así: `. nombrescript.sh` como indica la respuesta (ve la actualización).

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la aclaración. Según tenía entendido, `. script` o `source script` se puede usar con scripts igualmente. De hecho, al ejecutar el script que hice con `. script` se ejecuta y activa el entorno virtual. ¿Podrías explicarme al respecto? [Fuente](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107969/what-is-the-difference-between-source-x-x-and-x-in-bash).

Comment: Ambas soluciones funcionan esencialmente. En el getopts solamente se puede activar un entorno virtual por sesión de bash, mientras que la otra solución funciona bien (nada más hay que quitar las comillas en la línea del comando source), lo que ayudó mucho fue el hecho de ejecutar el script así ". script", puedes ver el cuerpo del problema al final como deje las cosas para que funcionaran bien para mí.

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo que tengo es un pequeño `alias` en mi `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias activa='source env/bin/activate'
```

De este modo, cuando estoy en un directorio concreto que tiene un `env/` como subdirectorio, escribo `activa` (o cualquier otro nombre que le quieras dar) y me busca el fichero `env/bin/activate` que hay en ese directorio en concreto.

Creo que es lo más práctico, pues normalmente quieres activar el *virtualenv* que hay en el directorio en el que estás.

Si quieres tener más visibilidad sobre qué entorno virtual estás activando, puedes añadirle un `echo` del tipo:

```
alias activa='echo "activando $PWD/env/bin/activate" && source env/bin/activate'
```

De este modo, al decir `activa` te saldrá un mensaje del tipo:

```
activando /home/tu_usuario/un_proyecto/env/bin/activate
```

Comment: Este método me soluciono algo y es que he intentado varios métodos de escribir el script y ninguno me muestra error, pero no me activa el entorno virtual, solo este. Aun que si tienes idea preferiría que me ilustraras como hacerlo introduciendo el nombre del entorno virtual y que así se active dicho entorno virtual. De cualquiera manera este me sirve como una solución temporal.

Comment: @codenoschool sería útil que mostraras tu código exacto, así como los errores que te dio. `read valor; source "$valor/env/bin/activate"` debería ser más que suficiente (suponiendo que está en env/).

Comment: Ya lo puse sobre el cuerpo de la pregunta, en el apartado "EDIT 2". Coloqué el código y otros detalles.

Comment: @codenoschool está todo bien pero te falta `source` en `~/envs/$name/bin/activate`. Debes decir `source ~"/envs/$name/bin/activate"`.

Comment: Tienes razón, ahora ya lo corregí. Al final del cuerpo de la pregunta puedes ver la solución a la que llegué para que funcionara el script en mi caso.

Comment: @codenoschool ¡qué bien que lo solucionaras! Tu solución es básicamente el script que Gustavo García proporcionó. Lo ideal sería que aceptaras su respuesta y, si hay algo relevante, publicaras una respuesta con tu solución. Mira en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) y [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Solo para completar las respuestas, ya existe algo parecido creado por Doug Hellmann. El nombre de esta herramienta es [virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/) y es para OS X y Linux (puedes encontrar la versión para Windows en [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win)).

Entre otras cosas te permite:

- Gestionar tus entornos virtuales.
- Crear, borrar, copiar entornos virtuales.
- Usar un solo comando para cambiar de entorno virtual.

### Instalación

Usando `pip`:

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

### Configuración

```
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

### Uso

Algunos ejemplos:

```
$ mkvirtualenv env1
Installing
setuptools..........................................
....................................................
....................................................
...............................done.
(env1)$ pip install django
...
(env1)$ mkvirtualenv env2
Installing setuptools...............................
....................................................
....................................................
........... ...............................done.
(env2)$ ls $WORKON_HOME
env1            env2            hook.log
(env2)$ workon env1
(env1)$
```

Comment: Hace unos meses estaba investigando sitios de deploy (de manera rápida) y vi ese comando de "workon" en pythonanywhere, solamente que no sabía como se llamaba el módulo. Efectivamente me puede ser muy útil a la hora de trabajar de manera más ordenada.